# Proving a real number must be an integer given certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $r$ be a real number such that $n^r$ is a natural number for all natural numbers $n$. Prove that $r$ is a natural number.

If $r$ is rational it is easy to prove that it must be an integer.

Comment: Note;  if $r$ is algebraic but not rational then $n^r$ is transcendental, by [Gelfond Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), so the only relevant case here is when $r$ is transcendental.

Comment: You already asked this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964419/interesting-number-theory-and-analysis

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  True, but that question was (in my view, at least) closed inappropriately.  The cited duplicate does not appear to be a duplicate at all.

Comment: This problem appeared on the $1971$ Putnam exam.  You can find a solution [here](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html).

Comment: Might be worth noting that, as far as I am aware, if you merely require that $2^r,3^r$ be integers I believe the problem is still open, though it is enough if you also add $5^r$.  See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well) for more detail.

Comment: Well, I was trying to prove it "on the fly"... I'll better give up :)

Comment: Please do not delete and re-post questions in order to short circuit the close/reopen process. If your question is closed, edit it to include more context. If it was closed as a duplicate and you disagree, don't just write "I don't understand why", explain why you think it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @lulu: That has nothing to do with that. Deleting and reposting as a shortcut for having the question reopened undermines the process of closure and reopening. We have the review queue, we have the reopen requests meta thread, and we even have a chatroom for these kind of things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Ok.

Comment: lol @AsafKaragila

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?